# changes core/Common.php results net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2, codeigniter-2

After the server PHP upgrade I am getting the following error with PHP Version 5.6.2 on Apache 2.0

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 257
```

then i changed core/Common.php

```
return $_config[0] =& $config
```

into

```
$_config[0] =& $config; return $_config[0];
```

This resulted  too many redirects for a site,and got 302 error

Comment: I would trace the error back to the line in your controller that causes this issue. The problem is with something in your own controller or view, and you should not fix this by editing a core file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in core/Common.php

add this line on line no 257

```
return $_config[0];
```

i have try it its working for me when i upgraded my codeigniter version

Comment: changed `return $_config[0] =& $config;`    into   `$_config[0] =& $config; return $_config[0];  ` then i got this new redirect loop error

Comment: have you do changes in your default controller any redirection conditions in that controller?

Comment: No, i just changed 257th line of Common.php

Comment: have you removed this line $_config[0] =& $config and add  this line return $_config[0]; ?? right?

Comment: newly added two lines                                                                                    `$_config[0] =& $config; `                                                                                  `return $_config[0];`